# codeigniter calling methods in controller from js

Tags: javascript, forms, codeigniter, models

Hello I am a beginner in codeigniter framework and I have some problems.

I made an registration form, and after I press button *REGISTER* i would like to call a js function `formValidation()` that should check some basic things (like whether each field is filled or not).

And if everything is OK, then i want to submit those values from registration form to a controller's method `checkExistance()` whose task is to call the method from users_model `checkDoesUserExists($username)` and that method will check whether we have the user with that username in our database, and he will  return true or false depending on the results from base.

And my question is how do I submit data from my form and to call controllers method and pass the data to that method (like $username ...), and if I miss anything else in the code?

I really don't have any idea how to call the controllers method from my js?
Thanks to everyone willing to help me!

This is my html page: registration.php

```
<html>
<head>

    <script>
        function formValidation(){
            var username = document.registrationForm.username.value;
            var email = document.registrationForm.email.value;
            var name = document.registrationForm.name.value;
            var surname = document.registrationForm.surname.value;

             if(username == ""){
                alert('enter your username');
                document.registrationForm.username.focus();
            }else if(email == ""){
                alert('enter your email');
                document.registrationForm.email.focus();
            }else if(name == ""){
                alert('enter your name');
                document.registrationForm.name.focus();
            }else if(surname == ""){
                alert('enter your surname');
                document.registrationForm.surname.focus();
            }else{
                //alert('OK');
                document.registrationForm.submit();
                //I would like to call controller's method from here and to pass data to that method - "checkExistance"
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>


    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration form</legend>                
            <form name="registrationForm" method="post" aciton="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Username</td><td> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="insert your username"> </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Email</td><td> <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="insert your email"> </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Name</td><td> <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="insert your name"> </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Surname</td><td> <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="insert your surname"> </td></tr>

                        <tr><td> <input type="button" value="REGISTER" onclick="formValidation()"> </td><td> <input type="reset" value="Clear form">  </td></tr>
                    </table>                    
            </form>               
        </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my controler : users_controler.php

```
<?php

class Users_controler extends CI_Controller{

function index(){
    $this->load->view('registration');
}


function checkExistance(){
    $username['username'] = $this->input->post('username');//// ????   This is probably wrong

    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $result = $this->users_model->checkDoesUserExists($username);
    if($result == true){
        echo 'OK - username is available, we will now activate in the users_model "addUser()" method to add a user in database';
    }  else {
        echo 'ALERT - User already exists';
    }     
}
}
```

This is my model : users_model.php

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model{

function checkDoesUserExists($username){
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from users where username = '$username'");
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function addUser(){
    // Adding the user in this step
}   
}
```

Thanks to everyone willing to help me!!!!

Comment: Did you try ajax and jquery?

Comment: you need AJAX if you want to request information from the backend at time of running the JS

Comment: No i didn't try with AJAX or with jQuery. Can you give me an example how to do that with AJAX or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

use form validation in your controller action function as bellow.

```
<?php

   class Form extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[users.email]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
}

public function username_check($str)
{
    if ($str == 'test')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

}
```

here you need to focus on callback function username_check, similar to change you need to do in checkExistance function, rest you can learn here.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: Thank you, i will try to do this.
But i am still wondering on how to call some controllers method and to pass data do that method using js, or ajax or jQuery when i click on button?

Comment: this line callback controller function in form validation. $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');  here username_check is controller function and callback is way to call controller function for validation.

Comment: maybe i don't understand this very good, but you call from method index()  in this line $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');  method username_check($str), but i want to call from js which has been placed my in html page :registration.php, i want to call method from controler. and to submit him the data

Comment: from js, you need to use ajax other wise form validation of codeigniter also  have feature to call back any conroller function and validate user input and then show message with form_error function of codeigniter

Comment: And can you give me some example how to call method using ajax and to transfer the data. It would be very helpful to me to use it like a template

Comment: check this http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/checking-username-availability-with-ajax-using-jquery/